# Zend application problem on iis6

Tags: zend-framework, iis-6, windows-server-2003

When I'm passing the URL like http://localhost/home/index/index in my application I'm getting the module=>default, controller=>index, action=>index. Whatever may be the URL i'm getting the same thing. I'm running the application on IIS6 in windows 2003 platform. If i'm overriding the module as 'home' in Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract=>getModuleName() method then my home page is coming fine. I'm unable to get where exactly it is overriding the value to 'default','index','index'. Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance

Update:
The problem is with $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL']. I'm getting the same URI into both $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] like /public_mvc/index.php. I'm not overriding the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'] anywhere in my code. My .htaccess code is like this.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin-mvc(.*)$ public_mvc/admin.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^[\w/\%]*(?:.(?!(?:js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$)[\w\%]*$)? public_mvc/index.php [I]

RewriteRule ^$ /home [r=301,nc]

I'm using ISAPI Rewrite 3 for URL Rewriting.

Comment: Do you have [IISRewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) installed?

Answer (score 0):

this is how Zend Framework handles the "default" module.

You can access your root path like this:

- domain.tld/
- domain.tld/index
- domain.tld/index/index
- domain.tld/default/index/index

all request will result in

- module: **default**
- controller: **index**
- action: **index**

**Update 1:**

Probably there is a static route for module **home** configured

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static

which sends requests for

- **/home**/index/index

to

- **/default**/index/index

**Update 2:**

Make sure you have Isapi_Rewrite installed as indicated here (search for IIS):

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

**Update 3:**

Add this rewirte rule to your .htaccess (as indicated in Zend article of **Update 2**):

```
RewriteRule ^[\w/\%]*(?:\.(?!(?:js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$)[\w\%]*$)? /index.php [I]
```

**Update 4:**
Try the following code in your .htaccess (it is the recommendation from Zend article of **Update 2**)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^[\w/\%]*(?:\.(?!(?:js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$)[\w\%]*$)? /index.php [I]
```

If this does not work, I'm not sure what the solution is. I'm not using IIS and not familiar with the particularities there...

Comment: This is how it works. However OP specified that he could type anything and it goes there, pointing to the fact that it is defaulting to the default page. In the OP's one specific example he typed `home/index/index`. This would obviously **not** go to `default/index/index` unless something was wrong with setup.

Comment: Please answer for my post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919695/problem-with-serverhttp-x-rewrite-url-on-iis6-isapi-rewrite

Comment: why do you open a new post which is related to the same issue?

Comment: I can't able to paste my code here. So thats why i've done this. Any thing wrong with this? Can you please help me here. I've deleted that post and edited here.

Comment: this is for comments. paste code to your initial question -> click "edit". then edit/paste your code...

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm redirecting to /home. But $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'] taking /public_mvc/index.php. If i overwrite the value like $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL']='/home' in setRequestUri() method of Zend_Controller_Request_Http class, then it is redirecting properly. Please look into my .htaccess code and give suggestions on this.

Comment: Note: I am not using IIS... did you take a look at the link I provided in my "update 2". there is a rewrite rule I am missing in your .htaccess.

Comment: Yes, I've added all those things. But there no change in the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'] path.

Comment: don't see the rewrite rule in your .htaccess code. take a look at my "Update 3"...

Comment: Yes. I've added the same thing only. No improvement. I'm very thankful for your quick response.

Comment: please update your initial question with the exact(!) content of your .htaccess file. otherwise it will be misleading for users which could potentially help you... and give credit to helpful answers... you will get more feedback from users...